# Can someone please help me work out what software is being used to generate these diagrams.

Tags: math-software

[Function Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCElB.jpg)

[Trigonometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIbud.jpg)

[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3YLE.jpg)

Comment: Try **FREE** GeoGebra: www.geogebra.org. I prefer GeoGebra Classic 5.0.

Comment: I have, but it's not the correct software.

Comment: To @FredClark: I didn't mean to say it is 'the best' math digital tool. In 'a sea' of similar and very good digital tools, it would be best to say: *the choice is yours!*

Answer (score 2):

I suggested **FREE** GeoGebra, and here you can see how 'powerful' is this software solution when we need to plot graphs of some functions:
[image]

Next, we are able to find the intersection points of a given graphs, the area of a region between them, and many more. Also, it is important that GeoGebra is multi-platform dynamic mathematics software.